# Function Approximation in Hilbert Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

$H$ is a Hilbert space and $\left(e_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathrm{N}}$ is an orthonormal sequence in $H.$

For each $x \in H$,

there exists a **unique sequence of scalars** $\left(c_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathrm{N}}$ such that

$x=\sum c_{n} e_{n}.$

**Question:**

How to prove that $c_n$ is unique?

Comment: Use the scalar product with $e_{n}$. It will give you an uniquely defined expression for $c_{n}$.

Comment: For fix $m$, we have $\left\langle x, e_{m}\right\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} e_{n}, e_{m}\right\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n}\left\langle e_{n}, e_{m}\right\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} \delta_{m n}=c_{m}$. So, $c_{m}=\left\langle x, e_{m}\right\rangle$, By the inner product, $c_{m}$ can be uniqely defined. Is it right?

Comment: Exactly! That is the proof.